# Qualtrics & Javascript Precise Timer Using Time Spend on a Page

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am doing research with an experiment using qualtrics and unfortunately I am completely new to coding. In my experiment a block of questions should be ended after a certain time (in this case 50 seconds). So far I have been using a solution (which I found here: https://research-it.wharton.upenn.edu/uncategorized/qualtrics-loop-merge-tips/) that appeared rather neat using a blank embedded variable "test_time", display logic and the following javascript code which I copied to every page of the block:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
     var elapsed = Date.now() - Number("${e://Field/test_time}");
     if (elapsed >= 50000){
     Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("test_time", 0);
}  
});
```

However, in the exported data when summing up information from timing questions that I included, I see that people have extremely varying time they actually can spend on the questions of the block (from 30 to almost 50 seconds). I am guessing this is due to the fact that the script uses the time of the clock, irrespective of lag caused by a bad internet connection or slow browser.

However, for my project it is important that people actually have the same time for the task. I suspect I could use the information of the timing questions, but somehow I can't access them in Javascript. Another idea is to record the difference between the page appearing and the click on the next button.

I appreciated any of your ideas and inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in embedded variable Q_TotalDuration, which is the elapsed survey time in seconds.  Set the start time of the block in the survey flow just before the block:

```
startBlock = ${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}
```

Then your JavaScript becomes:

```
var elapsed = parseInt("${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}") - parseInt("${e://Field/startBlock}");
if(elapsed >= 50) {
  //do something here
}
```

I don't understand what happens when the time limit is reached and time_test is set to zero in your original code.  It wouldn't have any impact on the current page. It seems like you should be setting up a timeout function to click the Next button when the time threshold is reached.